# Can Google Analytics be used for Gamification points?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am building something like a social network, I'd like to add some Gamification features to promote behavioral and loyalty. The thing is I can't just keep points, I'd like to have something of a Life-Time-Value that would put the time spent and reactions and so in action. I have found that it is possible through Google Data API. But **is it a good practice?** In comparison with only storing points or so in a Firestore field, I mean.
Thanks in advance.

I experimented with Firestore fields but this doesn't record the timeline of earning those points and how much earned recently for example.